# Subclassing UIButton giving me errors

Tags: swift, uibutton

When I run app and push buttons it causes crash "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x108656e70)

```
class MyButton: UIButton{

   var myValue: Bool

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       myValue = true
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController{

    //changed datatype from UIButton
    @IBOutlet var manyButtons: [MyButton]!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: MyButton){

        //Error here "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x108656e70)"

        print(sender.myValue)

    }
}
```

Incidentally, I noted that I was unable to connect buttons from storyboard like usual (cntrl and drag to outlet). I declared "manyButtons" as UIButton first to enable me to connect them from my storyboard. Then Later I changed datatype to MyButton. I believe I did same with IBAction

Comment: Actually you should get the (pointless) `fatalError` in `init?(coder` at once. Most likely the class of the buttons is not set to the subclass in Interface Builder.

Comment: FML, that's what it was. I didn't make MyButton the custom class on interface builder.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Select "MyButton" as custom class in identity inspector

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
class MyButton: UIButton{ 
   var myValue = true 
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The line

```
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
```

can lead to unkonwn crashes , so this isn't it's place as for sure you don't want to cause a crash when the buttons are loaded from IB the method `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called

The bad exception here means that the action can't cast the button in IB to the sender current type which means you wrongly set the class name

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: MyButton){
```

and to verify that change `(_ sender: MyButton){` to `(_ sender: UIButton){` then re-run

Comment: I clicked the button on storyboard and changed its class to MyButton. It fixed the problem